# sidebar - widgets versus code - options

Tags: sidebar

I decided to use Widgets in my sidebar on the advice of another designer who thought the site would take too long to load if I used the images I'm using for titles and branding. I'm dissatisfied with the outcome because the Image and Text widgets create too much white space in between sections, and I'm limited in what I can control.

I have two related questions. Does anyone know of an Image or Text Widget that will allow me to minimize the white space between sections? My images are very tightly cropped, so there's no reason for the white space other than the widgets creating it.

The second question is: if I decide not to use widgets at all, and just program the sidebar.php file to refer to image files in the media library and enter in the appropriate text -- is it detrimental to the site's functionality? I see a lot of very customized wordpress sidebars online, and I can't imagine they are using widgets. But maybe they are using a technique that is over my head? This is a twenty twelve child theme.

Guidance appreciated. The site is at internalcompass.us/castle right now.

kb

Comment: Can you edit the style sheet to remove margins or padding between the widgets?

Comment: The spacing you see between the widgets is just CSS (which is off-topic here as is the request for a plugin recommendation) For the rest, I am a bit confused. If you are loading images you are loading images. It doesn't matter if they are in the sidebar or not. In fact it sounds like the sidebar is unnecessarily complex for what you are doing. I am unsure why that option was suggested.

Comment: Got it. The white space is actually not affected by CSS changes to padding. I have 0 padding and 0 margins. Thank you for the feedback about the images not being loaded any faster through widgets. I'll try not using widgets for those areas in the sidebar and see how that works.